# ArcMap shapefiles won't overlap

Tags: overlay, shapefile

When I upload two shapefiles to ArcMap they are not overlapping. I have to click "Zoom to Layer" to see each one. I know I have to change the coordinate systems but I am unsure how... If anyone would like to see the data I am using, I am using an Oklahoma Counties Shapefile and the Tornado Shapefile provided by NOAA. The links to each are provided below:

[Oklahoma Counties Link](http://geo.ou.edu/cgi-bin/redesign.cgi?ft=db&template=DataLayer.htm&DataLayersID=17) I downloaded the statewide shapefile

[Tornado Link](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/gis/svrgis/): I downloaded the torn.zip for tornadoes from 1950-2016

How do I get these two shapefiles to overlap? I have spent hours trying to figure this and have been reading/searching other posts but but I am not getting anywhere. Any help that can be provided would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There is no projection defined on the county shapefile .Use the Define projection tool to project it to the projection defined in the textfile.Its(Geographic Coordinate system,NAD1983_2011) .
Also to better help overlay them add the USA counties data from ArcGIS Online and then proceed to add the county and tornado shapefiles and it seemed to work just fine

I have attached a picture below with a definition query on the tornado file to Oklahoma city.
image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8EWw.jpg)